# Can not build Google Maps SDK for IOS version 1.7.0 with iOS6.1 sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've just updated to GMS version 1.7.0 and can not build successfully with **Base SDK iOS6.1**.

- I could build GMS version 1.7.0 with Base SDK iOS7.0 successfully.
- I also could build old GMS version 1.6.0 with Base SDK iOS6.0 or 7.0 successfully.

Below is my error content:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_glMapBufferRange",
>   referenced from:
>         gmscore::renderer::BufferObject::MapBuffer() in GoogleMaps(BufferObject.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Can someone give me advice, thank you for your help.

Comment: Try running it on a device instead of the simulator.

Comment: I tried both on Simulator and Device and the results are the same. More over I used Demo source from Api to build but it can not either.

Comment: @csnguyen so how did you end up fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and has been searching for 2days for solution. But suddenly i got the solution myself. It happens when you use more than one SDK in the simulator. The SDK was not compatible with my project. I was using SDK iOS 6 and SDK iOS 7 both. And SDK iOS 6  was creating this error. Once i delete the SDK iOS 6 and restarted my xCode, it worked perfectly fine. Both in simulator and device.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, but I do want to build GMS version 1.7.0 by SDK iOS6 for the theme of IOS6. I could build the previous version of GMS by SDK iOS6 normally, but seem Google changed something and it's not work on SDK iOS6 anymore.

Comment: The SDK iOS7 will work out for you to create the theme of iOS6. But if you want the GMS theme to be the previous one then that's only possible with a previous version of GMS. Because Google has changed a lot of thing in there. you can read GMap tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like _glMapBufferRange is an OpenGLES 3.0 function, while iOS6.1 only has OpenGLES 2.0:

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml